# URL Parameters in the new Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, url-parameters

Google recently moved to a new Search Console. In the old Search Console it's (in February 2019 still) possible to tell how Googlebot should interpret URL parameters.

> Help Google crawl your site more efficiently by indicating how we should handle parameters in your URLs.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/crawl-url-parameters?hl=en&authuser=0&siteUrl=https://example.com/&prop=go

[image]

Are these URL Parameters settings still available in the new Search Console? If so, where?

Also interesting: are the settings from the old Search Console still active even if this cannot be changed in the new Search Console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is not yet available in the new Search Console.   However, you can continue to use it in the old Search Console.  Setting up URL parameters still affects your site even it can't be done from the new Search Console.

[Google recently said](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2019/01/focusing-on-new-search-console.html) that certain features of the old Search Console are being retired in March 2019:

- Crawl errors
- Sitemaps reports
- User management
- HTML suggestions
- Property sets
- Andoid Apps
- Blocked resources

These all have replacement in the new Search Console or Google says they are not useful enough to port over.

Google hasn't said anything about the URL Parameters Tool.  That means you will still be able to use it in the old Search Console, even after March.

It is unclear whether Google plans to eventually port this feature to the new Search Console.  Google has not announced a plan for the feature, nor a timeline.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the URL Parameters Tool in the old search console, but whatever you input is then ignored in the new search console, so it is of no use. Until the URL Parameters function is available in the new search console we can do nothing.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?